# numpy handling equation input when input is structure "String"

Tags: python, numpy, equation

hi below is my code to solve linear equation, user must type coefficient and right side of the equation.
it works well but how to change code to handle input is "String" when it is something like "5x - 6y =10"

```
import numpy as np


a = list(map(int,input("type equation ex) 5x+ 6y = 10 >> 5 6 10").split()))

a = np.asarray(a)
b = list(map(int, input(("type equation ex) 5x+ 6y = 10 >> 5 6 10").split()))
b = np.array(b)

e = np.array([a[0:2], b[0:2]])
f = np.array([a[2],b[2]])

x = np.linalg.solve(e, f)
print(x)
```

Comment: `numpy` can't do that.  In this specific case, it would be easy for you to remove the variables and the plus signs to produce the array.

Comment: you can use `split('=')` to make left & right side then check using `find` or `index` to x & y value. you can play with string before passing to numpy

Comment: Basically you have decide how general of an expression you are prepared to parse, and when you tell the user - "can't do that".  Splitting is a powerful tool, but if you allow terms like '4x' you have to decide for yourself what's the coefficient, and what's the variable.  Or do you first translate it to '4*x'?  Just a lot of fun-n-games with strings :)

Comment: @hpaulj what i mean is 4 is coefficient and x is variable could you give me a clue to split coefficient and insert it to np.array?